# Finding column number of a stored range value in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I stored a range of cells in an array by the code bellow:

```
MyArr()=sheet1.range(x1:y1)
```

X and y change. I have no problem with the array, it works well.

Through a loop I read array values, if lets say a value is "sample", then I need to find a cell's value in a fixed row and the column of "Sample".

I can not find the column number or row number of the stored ranges.

When i type MyArr (1,n) it returns the value but when i try `MyArr(1,n)`. column to get this value column number it doesnt act like an object and gives error. n is related Array index number.

when I store a range in an array, how can I get row or column numbet of this stored range value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `MyArr() = MyRange` you're writing a [Let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/let-statement) Statement, which is assigning Values from an expression to a variable. `MyRange` accesses its default member which is `MyRange.Value`. Since it is a multi-cell range, it creates an array of Variant values which get saved into `MyArr`.

This is a long way to say, you're not putting a range into an array, you're taking the values of the range and putting them into an array. So once you have the values in `MyArr`, the elements have no members  like `Range.Row` or `Range.Column` because they are not objects, just  values.

If you want to save the Range as an object you can do

```vb
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Sheet1.Range("x1:y1")
```

If you need to access the values from `MyRange` you can do either `MyRange.Cells(1,1).Value` or `MyRange.Value()(1,1)` which will be the same as what you had in `MyArr`.

But since it is saved in a Range Object, you have access to all the object members of a range object. For example you can find the row and column -  `MyRange.Cells(1,1).Row` and `MyRange.Cells(1,1).Column`. Or you can find other values in the same row like `MyRange.Cells(1,1).EntireRow.Cells(5)`.

Comment: So storing range values in a range gives us range objects as many as member of the range.

Comment: The Range Object is still a member of the worksheet, which you can see by doing `Range.Parent`. What you're doing is saving a reference or a shortcut to that Object. The variable name `MyRange` is just a reference. So the range and the values never leave the sheet, but you can quickly refer to them by doing `MyRange.Cells(i, j).Value`